# Can I voluntarily fail the roll for the Collapsed Room?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

The Collapsed Room has the following text:

> You must attempt a Speed roll of 5+ to avoid falling. If you fail the roll, draw a basement tile and put it in play. You fall there and take 1 die of physical damage.

Is it permitted to voluntarily fail the roll if I *want* to go to the basement and am willing to sacrifice the 1 die of physical damage?

Also, does the answer differ for forced movement? This came up for *Haunt 9: The Dance of Death*. In that haunt, players must make a Sanity roll or do the following:

> you must move toward the Ballroom by the shortest route through discovered rooms. You may perform other actions normally along the way if you wish.

In our case, the Collapsed Room was in the way of the Ballroom, and we were unsure as to whether we could voluntarily fail that room roll in order to get farther away.

So can I voluntarily fail the roll for the Collapsed Room?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. From the [FAQ](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/faqs/hoth):

> Collapsed Room -- Could a monster or explorer intentionally choose to fall through the floor of the collapsed room to get to the basement?
>
> > Yes. A hero would need to roll and take damage; a monster or traitor would not

For your second question, I do not believe the rules give a clear answer to this. I believe it is logical to say yes, you can fall down to avoid the Ballroom. This is because the instructions are specifically referring to how you choose to move, and it says you may perform other actions along the way. Falling down the collapsed room counts as "other actions", and it is not something that really falls within the question of where you are moving to. I believe that when it tells you where you must move to, it is referring to which direction you take each time you use movement to leave a room.

Also note that if the Collapsed Room has already been discovered, an explorer can choose to walk through it freely without needing to roll:

> Only the explorer who first discovers the Collapsed Room needs to make the Speed roll listed there. Thereafter, any explorer entering the room can either ignore the room ability or use it intentionally, in which case that explorer still takes the damage. Falling to the basement doesn’t count as moving a space.

Answer (score 5):

No, not in this situation.

---

You don't roll when entering a previously-discovered Collapsed Room. From page 6 of the rules,

> Only the explorer who first discovers the Collapsed Room needs
>   to make the Speed roll listed there. Thereafter, any explorer
>   entering the room can either ignore the room ability or use it
>   intentionally, in which case that explorer still takes the damage.
>   Falling to the basement doesn’t count as moving a space.

In this situation, however, your character wouldn't choose to jump down. They do not want to get further away. They are compelled to reach the room as fast as possible.

---

Gendolkari's answer makes no sense. They say one can choose to fail the roll, but then follows up with the rule saying one doesn't even get a roll.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say that the rules require you as the player to make the same decisions that the character you are playing as would logically do.

Comment: @GendoIkari, There's only one decision: To jump down (by not rolling the dice) or to try to make it across. The player can't decide not to roll any more than he can decide to move the miniature away from the ballroom. The compelled behaviour of the character limits the actions of the player.

Comment: Also, note that you do NOT have to roll to avoid falling if the room has already been discovered. You just choose whether to cross or to fall. This is clarified in the second edition rules. https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1239262/timing-using-dog-and-collapsed-room

Comment: @GendoIkari, Adjusted my answer. I'm surprised your didn't adjust your own!?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have an actual rules quote until now (I own first edition, and second edition rules aren't available online as far as I know). Though this particular rule doesn't directly answer either of the questions, it's certainly related enough that it's good to be in the answer.

Comment: @Gendolkari, http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=ah/downloads

Comment: Until now I was pretty sure that they'd never updated that link for the new edition. But, I just checked, and both that link AND my edition 1 rules have that rule about Collapsed Room. I thought it was a new clarification to the second edition. So now I don't know if they even updated the rulebook for second edition or not. If they did, I can't easily tell if that link is first or second edition.

Comment: @Gendolkari, Link is probably first edition, especially since the page number is different than the one mentioned on the BGG post mentioning second edition.